# vkCmdCopyBufferToImage for Texture2DArray

Tags: vulkan, texture2d

I'm trying to create Image array from 576x112 texture with single channel.
I try create 48x112 per layer, so arrayLevel is set to 12.

[image: input texture]

Then I upload data using staging buffer and it looks like this
[image: result]

I try different bufferRowLength, final image become more ugly, and bufferImageHeight don't affects the final result

```cpp
vk::BufferImageCopy buffer_image_copies[12] = {};
for (u32 i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    // Copy only the first layer of the texture
    buffer_image_copies[i].bufferOffset = 0;
    buffer_image_copies[i].bufferRowLength = 48;
    buffer_image_copies[i].bufferImageHeight = 112;
    buffer_image_copies[i].imageSubresource.aspectMask = vk::ImageAspectFlagBits::eColor;
    buffer_image_copies[i].imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    buffer_image_copies[i].imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = i;
    buffer_image_copies[i].imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    buffer_image_copies[i].imageOffset = vk::Offset3D(0, 0, 0);
    buffer_image_copies[i].imageExtent = vk::Extent3D(48, height, 1);
}
command_buffer.copyBufferToImage(staging_buffer, car_volume_texture.image, vk::ImageLayout::eTransferDstOptimal, 12, buffer_image_copies);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was wrong size in memcpy when data copied to staging buffer, everything is ok now